# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an error that I don't understand and I don't know how to solve it, altough having tried a lot. The error is:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6/gradle-7.6.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6/gradle-7.6.pom
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

So something is wrong with my Java edition or the connection to the build.grandle file. I have Java JDK 19. Here is the code of the build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/android/maven2'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the gradle.wrapper-properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

According to this website https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html, Java 19 is compatible with gradle-7.6. So I dont understand why I still get the error.

**Update**: I tried what is suggested but still get an error message. Here are my files

build.gradle (DrinkServer):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/android/maven2'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.drinkserver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        resConfigs "en", "de"
        viewBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    def nav_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'


}

gradle-wrapper. properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I get the error message "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'DrinkServer' -> androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0 -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20
"

This is kind of strange as I don't use Kotlin at all (only Java)

**Reminder**: As I still have this problem (altough having spent quite some time on it) I would like to remind you on this question. Does anyone have a suggestion as to why this is happening and how to solve this issue? I'll appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 5):

I could not see any  gradle version 7.6 in distribution.
[gradle distribution snapshot](https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/)
Can you change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
```

```
dependencies {
        classpath ('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
    }
```

Please add this in your build.gradle
Make sure distribution gradle url is 7.6.1 and in dependancies its like 7.4.2

[image: Graddlewrapper]

[image: Build.gradle]

Comment: Thanks Jeeva for your answer. I tried what you suggested but still get the error message `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.`. I think the problem might be in the line ``classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6'` of the build.gradle file, because when I for example use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4'` I get the error message `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.`

Comment: @VanessaF https://stackoverflow.com/a/73968815/6059583 Please follow this answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728038/6059583

Comment: Thanks Jeeva for your comment. When trying what is said in your suggested links I get the following error message `The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'DServer' -> androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0 -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20`.

Comment: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: @VanessaF im not sure what you have tried in build.gradle i tried the steps in link and it worked for me

Comment: @VanessaF i have updated my answer hope you have done the same

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried what you suggested but still get an error message. I updated my question with the new files.

Comment: Now I get the error `Execution failed for task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5710727a
`